# Regex match group based on common groupings

Tags: javascript, regex

Good evening,

I'm trying to group the below text so it will allow me to replace with a `<ol>$1</ol>`. Seems simple enough but I can't master the greediness.

Sample text (I'm aware its a repeated list, I copy+pasted for an example to show separation):

```
<h4>Properties</h4>
<dl><dd> <a href="/page/Oxygen">Oxygen</a> is <a href="/page/gas">gas</a> at <a href="/page/STP">standard temperature and pressure</a>.</dd></dl>

<h4>Testing for Oxygen</h4>
<li>A1</li>

<li>A2</li>

<li>A3</li>

<h4>Other Properties</h4>
<dl><dd> <a href="/page/Oxygen">Oxygen</a> is <a href="/page/gas">gas</a> at <a href="/page/STP">standard temperature and pressure</a>.</dd></dl>


<h4>Testing for Something Else</h4>
<li>B1</li>

<li>B2</li>

<li>B3</li>
```

The last entry can be either end-of-string or preceding another '\n'

I would like the 2 matches to be

```
<li>A1</li>

<li>A2</li>

<li>A3</li>
```

and

```
<li>B1</li>

<li>B2</li>

<li>B3</li>
```

So I can wrap in some `<ol>...</ol>`, simple enough. [There are other un-order lists on the page so using a temporary `<lio>` tag in my actual code then replacing with `<li>` at the end of the function].

I've gotten to the point of the below but its too greedy and starting at the first (A1's) `<li>` and stopping at the last (B3's) `</li>`

Current match:

```
<li>A1</li>

<li>A2</li>

<li>A3</li>

<h4>Other Properties</h4>
<dl><dd> <a href="/page/Oxygen">Oxygen</a> is <a href="/page/gas">gas</a> at <a href="/page/STP">standard temperature and pressure</a>.</dd></dl>


<h4>Testing for Something Else</h4>
<li>B1</li>

<li>B2</li>

<li>B3</li>
```

Current search string: `(?!\<\/li\>.)*(\<li\>[^¬]+(\<\/li\>))(?!\<\/li\>)` which captures the entire thing on Full Match (groups are a bit squiffy)

Doing this in JavaScript.

Any advice?

Thank you,

Comment: Using regular expressions to parse HTML is generally a bad idea. JavaScript has a built-in DOM parser.

Comment: This project goes well beyond parsing html. It’s parsing another mark up language. It’s all taken care of except <ol>’s

Comment: Can there be other tags nested inside the `<li>`?

Comment: No. That would add tabbed depth which is not what I’m looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Got it licked

This does it:

```
(\<lio\>[\w\W]*?)\n+(\<[^l]|\0|\w|¬)
```